# Flutter Cloud Firestore fails on calling getDocuments() on iOS

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue with fetching some data from Cloud Firestore in my flutter project. Code is as follows:

```
  void test () async {
    var data = await Firestore.instance.collection("markers").getDocuments();
    print("${data.documents.length}");
  }
```

However, on the console I get the following:

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(178)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("documents")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/lib/object_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      new QuerySnapshot._ (file:///Users/jacobpyke/Development/flutter/v1/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.9.6/lib/src/query_snapshot.dart:10:57)
#2      Query.getDocuments (file:///Users/jacobpyke/Development/flutter/v1/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.9.6/lib/src/query.dart:100:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HomePage.test (package:KaffeeBar/screens/home/home_page.dart:39:63)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      HomePage.build (package:KaffeeBar/screens/home/home_page.dart:45:5)
#5      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3788:28)
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3735:15)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/fra<…>
```

It just struck me as a bit of a strange error. A screenshot of my firestore structure can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCnNW.jpg

[image]

And yes there is data inside the Document, so it shouldnt be returning Null because of no data.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: Furthermore, all throughout my app the Firestore seems to have stopped working. In some areas its still functions fine, however in some ottthers it returns null values

EDIT2: Seems I tried to compile the app on Android and it flat out doesnt compile due to the Firebase Plugins.

```
Note: /Users/jacobpyke/Development/flutter/v1/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.3.1+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/jacobpyke/Development/flutter/v1/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-4.0.0+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/jacobpyke/Development/flutter/v1/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_performance-0.1.0+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseperformance/FirebasePerformancePlugin.java:71: error: cannot access zzf
    trace.start();
         ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzf not found
Note: /Users/jacobpyke/Development/flutter/v1/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_performance-0.1.0+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseperformance/FirebasePerformancePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

EDIT 3: After Getting the App to compile, it works perfectly fine on android. So perhaps something wrong with the firebase GoogleInfo-Service.plst

Comment: Thanks for the title update!! Sorry for the vagueness

Comment: I'm facing the same issue (getDocuments() error) - but only on ios. Android seems to work fine.

Comment: I think Ill file a bug on the repo then. Doesn’t seem to just be me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this issue was a part of a bug within the Cloud Firestore plugin for Flutter. As such, This issue has been resolved as of update `0.9.7`. In order to fix the issue, update the cloud firestore plugin in your `pubspec.yaml` file to `cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7` and run `flutter packages get` Source can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29423)